# cannot import lightgbm - error with pandas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, lightgbm

[image]

Does anyone have a same problem and know some solutions?

I recently used lightgbm(maybe few days ago), but suddenly I cannot import it.

It says

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.strings' has no attribute 'StringMethods'
```

I want to resolve this problem quickly

Comment: Have you updated pandas?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Comment: @jlandercy yeah I updated it my pandas version is 2.0.3 and lightgbm 3.3.5

Comment: @Robert sorry I'm first here I will keep in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unexpectedly, I resolve this problem.

For people who have same obstacles, this might help.

```
pip install --upgrade pandas "dask[complete]"
```